# Using ArcPy with Python 3.7 instead of default Python 2.7 that comes with ArcMap 10.6.1?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, installation, python-3

I want to use ArcPy with Python 3.7. I tried setting the paths to `arcpy` but Python 3.7 doesn't `import arcpy` properly.

Is it possible to use a Python version outside of default version that ships with ArcMap 10.6?

Comment: Looks like you will have to use Arc Pro to access Python 3.x. More details here: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013224.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to say, the answer is no.

- ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap) supports Python 2.7 (32/64)
- ArcGIS Pro supports Python 3.x (64 only)

I try to write my ArcGIS python scripts to run over all supported pythons (ie those stacks released with ArcGIS) if possible. Of course can't always be done, but often it can be.

Some versions work better than others, as the support article says.

[FAQ: What version of Python is used in ArcGIS?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013224)

Answer (score 0):

It's all correct. You can't use arcpy version 2.7 with pyhton 3,but...

You can launch a script in python 2 from python 3
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863832/calling-python-2-script-from-python-3

If you share your process you can work!